# Why am I getting Traceback error in my python code

Tags: python

```
def min_op(n,base):
    if(base[n]!=None):
        result=base[n]
    elif(n==1):
        result=1
    else:
        if(n%2==0):
            result=1+min(min_op(n//2,base),min_op(n-1,base))
            base[n]=result
        else:
            result=1+min_op(n-1,base)
            base[n]=result
    return result
```

here is the error i got
Runtime Error:

```
Runtime ErrorTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/d7106f7b35cdcbcb097332ba5e88b383.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(min_op(n,base))
  File "/home/d7106f7b35cdcbcb097332ba5e88b383.py", line 8, in min_op
    result=1+min(min_op(n//2,base),min_op(n-1,base))
  File "/home/d7106f7b35cdcbcb097332ba5e88b383.py", line 8, in min_op
    result=1+min(min_op(n//2,base),min_op(n-1,base))
  File "/home/d7106f7b35cdcbcb097332ba5e88b383.py", line 8, in min_op
    result=1+min(min_op(n//2,base),min_op(n-1,base))
  File "/home/d7106f7b35cdcbcb097332ba5e88b383.py", line 11, in min_op
    result=1+min_op(n-1,base)
  File "/home/d7106f7b35cdcbcb097332ba5e88b383.py", line 8, in min_op
    result=1+min(min_op(n//2,base),min_op(n-1,base))
  File "/home/d7106f7b35cdcbcb097332ba5e88b383.py", line 11, in min_op
    result=1+min_op(n-1,base)
  File "/home/d7106f7b35cdcbcb097332ba5e88b383.py", line 8, in min_op
    result=1+min(min_op(n//2,base),min_op(n-1,base))
  File "/home/d7106f7b35cdcbcb097332ba5e88b383.py.................
```

Comment: This looks like a stack overflow.

Comment: What do you expect to be returned from `min_op(0, base)`?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/must-do-coding-questions-for-companies-like-amazon-microsoft-adobe/#DP

Answer (score 1):

Your error is a stack overflow, referred to be python as:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

The reason for the recursion error is that you have the line:

```
result=1+min(min_op(n//2,base),min_op(n-1,base))
```

where the `min_op(n-1,base)` part means that there is always a way for the program to recurse downwards `n` times, which in the case of your `Minimum Operations` coding problem constraints, the value for `N` could be as high as 10^4 which exceeds the python stack depth.

This mean that the way you are tackling this problem is unsuited to a recursive solution, except that this part is completely redundant and your code could be fixed by simply replacing the line with:

```
result = 1 + min_op(n // 2, base)
```

With this change, your program should run quicker and without error.